# How to implement this create function correctly?

Tags: c, arrays, struct, queue

I'm trying to make a function to make a priority queue. My structs are this:

```
struct node {
  char *item;
  struct node *next;
};

struct queue {
  struct node *start;
  struct node *end;
};

struct priority_queue {
  struct queue **aoq;
  int x;
};
```

My function that I want to implement is:

```
struct priority_queue *priority_queue_create(int x);
```

Here, as seen in the structure priority_queue, struct queue **aoq is essentially an array of queues, which is want I want. int x, as in the function header, is the number of queues in the array.

My take on it is this:

```
struct priority_queue *priority_queue_create(int x) {
  struct priority_queue *pq = malloc(sizeof(struct priority_queue));
  pq->x = x;
  pq->aoq = malloc(x* sizeof(struct queue));
  return pq;
}
```

Where I put the 3 comment lines in the code above is where I suspect my error to be. I want to be able to do something like: if x = 3, there should be an array with 3 queues in it, and I suppose I'll be able to access it by doing something like

```
pq->aoq[0] /// to access the first queue in the array, or
pq->aoq[2] /// to access the third queue in the array
```

Can anyone help my fix my implementation? Thanks in advance.

---

Edit:
Other implementation I've tried:

```
struct priority_queue *priority_queue_create(int x) {
  struct priority_queue *pq = malloc(sizeof(struct priority_queue *));
  pq->x = x;
  pq->aoq = malloc(x * sizeof(struct queue *));
  for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i) {
    pq->aoq[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct queue));
  }
  return pq;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, they were typos. I edited above.

Comment: `malloc(x * sizeof(struct queue))` should be `malloc(x * sizeof(struct queue *))`

Comment: Then you need to allocate memory for each of the `struct queue` nodes and assign to `pq->aoq[i]`.

Comment: I just tried that. It's not working for me.

Comment: "it's not working" doesn't tell us what the problem is. Update your code in the question and describe clearly what "not working" means.

Comment: In response to your previous comment, how would I do that (the allocation for memory for struct queue).

Comment: `for (i =0; i < x; i++) pq->aoq[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct queue));`

Comment: Or change `aoq` definition to be an array of `struct queue` rather than an array of `struct queue *`. That is `struct queue *aoq;`. Then can allocate the whole array with single malloc: `pq->aoq = malloc(x * sizeof(struct queue));`. That's appropriate if you want all the queues allocated up front.

Comment: Could edit the post with the updated version of your code?

Comment: I put a little section with other implementations I've tried with the suggestions given.

Comment: @kaylum In concern to 2 comments above, I tried implementing what you recently suggested above. I when running, it's giving me a segmentation-fault-on-null-address error. As for your most recent comment, I'm not quite understanding how changing to `struct queue *aoq` would help because wouldn't that mean it's pointing to a queue rather than an array of queues?

Comment: `struct queue *aoq` can point to a single `struct queue` but it can also be an array of `struct queue` (a single one can be considered just an array of 1).

Answer (score 0):

From the code that you posted, I think this is the functionality that you want. You were missing the allocation of memory for the queues inside `struct priority_queue`, that is:

```
pq-> aoq = malloc( x * sizeof(struct queue *));
```

Adding this and keeping what you already had (with a sample main function to test the function priority_queue_create()), we have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    char *item;
    struct node *next;
};

struct queue {
    struct node *start;
    struct node *end;
};

struct priority_queue {
    struct queue **aoq;
    int x;
};


struct priority_queue *priority_queue_create(int x) {
    struct priority_queue *pq = malloc(sizeof(struct priority_queue *));
    pq->x = x;

    pq-> aoq = malloc( x * sizeof(struct queue *));

    for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i) {
       pq->aoq[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct queue)); ///
    }

    return pq;
}

int main(){

    struct priority_queue * pq = priority_queue_create(3);
    char * str1 = "abcd";
    char * str2 = "abcde";

    pq->aoq[0]->start = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    pq->aoq[2]->start = malloc(sizeof(struct node)); 
    pq->aoq[0]->start->item = str1;
    pq->aoq[2]->start->item = str2;

    printf("%s - %s\n", pq->aoq[0]->start->item,  pq->aoq[2]->start->item);

    free(pq->aoq[0]->start);
    free(pq->aoq[2]->start);
    free(pq->aoq[0]);
    free(pq->aoq[1]);
    free(pq->aoq[2]);
    free(pq->aoq);
    free(pq);

}
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested but I'm getting a heap-buffer-overflow error for some reason. I changed my code in the question above so you can what I put.

Comment: What is the size of levels and why are you not using x to define the number of elements of the priority queue? BTW: levels is not initialized in the function so you may be allocating a huge amount of memory in the heap.

Comment: Sorry about that, just wrote the wrong thing. I replaced levels with x but the same issue occurs.

Comment: What size of x are you using and where does the code breaks?

Comment: x should be any number, and the code breaks where you have the 3 comment lines in your code.

Comment: Does the code that I posted above works as is on your machine? Can you edit your post again and add a small and complete example of your code for us to see what is not working? Without that I am afraid that I cannot help you further.